# Regexp for matching names followed by optional spaces, but ignoring comments

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contains mostly of names mapping to a certain list of numbers. I would like to parse this file, and I presume a regular expression would be good here. I have however two problems:

- The names can consist of either a word, or a word followed by more words, or a word with underscore. A word can also contain the following characters: `(/->)`
- There is a comment in the beginning of the file and at some other places which should not be included in the result. The comments are always a line of`---` followed by some text followed by another line of `---`

So if I have the following file

```
-----------------------------------
Comment
-----------------------------------
Ignore these lines
-----------------------------------
someVar                        0.0  1.0
some var with spaces           52   93
another var_with_underscores   3
some var with (special->chars) 13  37  95
another char/slash             132  
-----------------------------------
Another comment
-----------------------------------
yet another var               27.3  9
```

I want to return a dictionary

```
{"someVar": [0.0, 1.0], 
 "some var with spaces": [52, 93],
 "another var_with_underscores": [3],
 "another char/slash": [132]  
 "some var with (special->chars)": [13, 37, 95],
 "yet another var": [27.3, 9]}
```

If it's too much to ask for one question, I would be happy just knowing the regexp.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: your comment delimitation seems ambigous, how you could know the second comment is a comment and not stuff to parse ?

Comment: @shenshei: That is a good question, my guess is that a parseable line will always have at least one number at the end.
@steabert: I'm a newbie for regexps and what I have tried is so far only to match the parsable lines without special characters, somwhere along the lines of `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]*([a-zA-Z_]* )?` (a word optionally followed by more words.

Comment: @pg-robban the problem is if someone want to comment a parsable line, how could you know it's a comment or not ? else you could parse the line with `^(.*?)((?:\s+\d+)+)$` and then do `[int(i) for i in re.split(r'\s+', res[1]) if i]` to get the list of int

Comment: The input is generated by another program, so I think we can assume that once a line is a comment it stays a comment, and likewise for parsable lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may do what you're looking for:

```
import re

results = {}
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m = re.match(r'([^\d]+)(.*)', line.strip())
        if m and m.group(2):
            results[m.group(1).strip()] = [float(n) for n in m.group(2).split()]
```

Which on your *updated* example give:

```
{'some var with (special->chars)': [13.0, 37.0, 95.0]
 'another var_with_underscores': [3.0]
 'some var with spaces': [52.0, 93.0]
 'someVar': [0.0, 1.0]
 'another char/slash': [132.0]
 'yet another var': [27.3, 9.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

absurd one-liner:

```
dict((m.group(1),map(float,m.group(2).split())) for m in re.finditer('^(.*?)\s*([ \d\.]+)$',whole_thing,re.M))
```